# No activity LED after shorting GPIO pins 3 and 5 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, linux, pi-gpio

[image: Annotated GPIO header showing the two pins]

I accidentally connected the fan to GPIO pins 2 and 3 or 3 and 4 (I am not sure which pair I connected but not both pairs are tougher) and now my Pi won't boot up. It is showing a solid red light. But it won't boot. No blinking green light.

The green light just flashes for a millisecond when power is connected. When connected to the correct pin (power and Ground), the fan works correctly.

Did I kill my Pi or is there any way to fix this?

Actually, I can't remember which pair. I mean, I connected one of those pairs, not both pairs: GPIO2 and GPIO3 (or GPIO3 and GPIO4).

When everything is disconnected and the SD card is removed, and then connecting the power back, it shows the same symptoms. I forgot to mention one thing: The Ethernet LEDs are also not working/turning on in both situations, like with an SD card and booting without connecting the fan and SD card.

Comment: NOTE GPIO 3 is physical pin 5; GPIO 5 is physical pin 29. I am guessing you connected GPIO2 & 3 (normally SDA1, SCL1). This should have no impact (although if these were programmed to be INPUT & OUTPUT you may have damaged the GPIO). If however you connected pin 1 (3.3V) to 5V or Gnd the Pi is dead.

Comment: When you say "3 and 5 (or 5 and 7)", do you mean that you connected it to both of these pairs of pins, or that you can't remember which pair? And when you say "GPIO pins...", are you referring to the physical pins, or their "GPIO ID"? As you say 4 and 5 are the correct pins (which are 5V and GND), then I guess you actually mean physical pins and not GPIO ID. So, for clarity, which *physical* pins did you actually connect to? Please [edit] your question and add the info there, and not in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you mean that you accidently connected SDA and SCL (pins 3&5) and SCL and GPCLK0 (pins 5&7). Neither of which would *seem* to be particularly catastrophic...

Comment: Disconnect EVERYTHING; remove the SD Card, then connect screen & apply power and describe what happens.

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments Edit your question. What is on the screen? See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: Actually, I don't have a screen until now I was using it headlessly. I don't have a micro HDMI to HDMI converter with me.

Comment: **You need to edit your question to make it clear if you are talking about pin numbers or GPIO numbers.**  Nothing that you seem to be describing would have damaged the Pi.

Comment: I don't know about the Pi specifically, but usually, shorting a GPIO pin on a microcontroller just damages that pin, at worst, so that it never works again. It's rare that it breaks the whole chip.

Comment: What does *"but not both pairs are tougher"* mean? Do you mean "but not both pairs are together" (which still doesn't make much sense) or just "but not both pairs"? From your comment later in the post it seems that you mean the latter. Please [edit] the question and fix the typo and clarify what you mean.